# How to modify GRUB to boot from e.g.: USB or CDROM?

Tags: grub

I have an installed Ubuntu (or e.g.: Fedora).
I need to boot from a CD or a pendrive.
I don't have access to the BIOS, so I can't set it to boot from a CDROM or from an USB flash drive. But I have root access to the installed Ubuntu (or e.g. Fedora). 
So I though I would somehow modify the GRUB so that after the machine "boots from the HDD", the "GRUB boots from the USB flash drive". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/SGD_BootScript_Usb_Boot_from_Cdrom

```
title Try USB HD0 boot
rootnoverify (hd0)
chainloader +1
boot
```

And

```
title Try USB HD1 boot
map (hd0) (hd1)
map (hd1) (hd0)
liveswap
rootnoverify (hd0)
chainloader +1
boot
```

I only know that it is possible. I do not know the specifics of how it works or how to do it so I don't know if extra steps are required to get GRUB to see the USB drive as a harddrive.

Comment: I will try this one out!